# Get data from Active Directory when a field in custom list is changed in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, active-directory, active-directory-import

I'm having a list with the following columns that have relation in the Active Directory: employee name, employee charge, department, extension number, employee's boss, and other text columns.

I'm trying to do 2 different things:

1. Get in the employee's name column a list of employee from the Active Directoy, and with that selected employee name, automatically fill the fields charge, department, extension number, employee's boss, with the data registered in the Active Directory.

Or

2. Fill the column fields charge, department, extension number, employee's boss using the "Created by" column, getting the information from the Active Directory of the user who is creating the ítem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you require the user info of the user other than the one that is logged in. It looks like the user whose information require can be other than logged in user.

It can be achieved in the form that is capturing the information (New / Edit) by querying user profile database or an event receiver that can do same query and update the fields.

I don't know how you can query the AD from the list but I think you should query the user profile database.

Comment: Using permissions I can restrict (or not) that the user that is logged in, is the one who I need the information.

Didn't know that I can query inside a field. Is that possible?

Comment: How are the forms for this list are built? using VS or SharePoint designer. For App pages / web parts you will require to use server side coding and SP designer forms you will require to use client side programming such as JSOM. Is this an existing form that you are modifying or a brand new development?

Comment: The form is the existing custom list web part, some columns are text type and others are election type. I have Designer in my pc but I didn't use it for that form.